# Calculating Hex In Cheat Engine Lua?

Tags: lua, hex, cheat-engine

I have a 4 byte hexadecimal value that I have a script to print out, But I want to now take that value then subtract the value C8 from it 37 times and save them as different variables each time, But the problem is I don't know how to do hexadecimal calculations in lua, If anyone can link me to any documentation on how to do this then that would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a hexadecimal literal in Lua by prefixing it with `0x`, as [stated in the reference manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html). I found this by googling "lua hex"; such searches usually get good results.

"Hexadecimal numbers" aren't anything special, hexadecimal is just a way to represent numbers, same as decimal or binary. You can do `1000-0xC8` and you'll get the decimal number `800`.

Answer (score 0):

Code to convert:

```
function convertHex()
    local decValue = readInteger(0x123456);
    hexValue = decValue
end

function hexSubtract()
    for i = 1,37 do
        local value = 0xC8
        hexValue = hexValue - 0xC8
        result = hexValue
        if i == 37 then
            print(result) --Prints dec value
            print(string.format('%X',result)); --Prints hex value
        end
    end
end
```

Replace `0x123456` with your address, use those functions like this `convertHex(),hexSubtract()`